# Third party cookie in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, cookies

I have a small js script and some clients, which use it. A few days ago a client came to me with the site on 2 differnet domains. My script store some data in cookies. When users within single site go to another domain - i can't access this cookie. I'm looking for a solution and come to a standstill. I have a server that hosts this script and i read that if site load script from my server - i can set cookie on my server domain. It's true? For example - if i go to [vk.com](http://vk.com) i can open dev tools and see cookies on domains .scorecardresearch.com and .tns-counter.ru. 
How can i do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't access windows/properties from different domains. Otherwise have a look at CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS